# postback validation causes an alert dialog to be displayed

Tags: asp.net, validation, alert

For some strange reason, an alert dialog with the text title "Message From Web page" and message "-" displays when posting back a form with validation. There are no custom validation scripts that display an alert window. I am debugging JavaScript using IE development toolbar? Is it possible to break into the code that displays the alert box? So far I have been unable to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the validation error was displayed by validation summary control with no display.
Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

`CTRL-SHIFT-J` (also under the Page > Developer > Debug JavaScript menu item) in chrome to debug javascript. Debuggin in chrome is easier than IE